# PHP Javascript variable help

Tags: php, javascript, variables

Is there any way to pass a javascript variable to a php function or simply assign a js variable to a php variable....???

test("asdas"); I need to update "asdas" to a dynamic value, i.e of the form,

Comment: There is nowhere to pass. Then JS starts to run, PHP is already dead. You can send it to another PHP script though, using usual POST or GET method.

Comment: @Srinivas: Yes you can. Valery's method will work just fine.

Comment: As a matter of fact, you have got your answer already here: [PHP Javascript variable help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297738/php-javascript-variable-help)

Comment: @OP: It would help if you told us *why* you need to pass a JS variable to PHP? Generally it's not needed, we might be able to suggest a better way of doing things.

Comment: @Kut: That wasn't clear at all. Are you trying to validate a form? If so, do it *twice*. Once with JavaScript only, and then again after the form is submitted. Don't use PHP to validate the form prior to submission. If however, you want to post some data without refreshing the page, use AJAX.

Comment: @Ralph: not validating, I need to check if the value entered by a user is in the db or not. if i use test("Asdasd"), where test() is a php function that queries the db and returns true or false, and display an alert box, it displays the output accurately. The only problem is that i need to use a text field value. like test(field value)...

Comment: @Kut: I'd call that a subsection of validation :) Validating that the input is unique. The answer is still AJAX, and what you're trying to do is quite common. You probably would have received better answers if you had written that up front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass value from js to PHP using ajax request or add js value to URL and then reload page.

**Variant #1 (using ajax)**:

JS side (jquery)

```
var js_var = 'hello';
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "js_var="+js_var,
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

PHP side

> $js_var = isset($_POST['js_var']) ? $_POST['js_var'] : '';

**Variant #2 (with page reload):**

JS side

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> <!--
> var js_var = 'hello';
> window.location = "http://www.yoursite.com/?js_var="+js_var;
> //-->
> </script>
> ```

PHP side

> $js_var = isset($_GET['js_var']) ? $_GET['js_var'] : '';

Comment: That would make the page reload which I would consider as looking bad.

Comment: @thejh: Then you have to use AJAX.

Comment: @thejh, for prevent page reload send params using ajax.

Comment: Don't forget too, that you can pass the value through a form as well.  `document.getElementById('MyInput').value = my_js_variable;`  then when it gets submitted, the value will go along with it.

Answer (score 2):

[you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297738/php-javascript-variable-help)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to send something from JS to PHP or from PHP to JS, use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). If PHP already knows the value it wants to send to JS when it's delivering the page, you can also embed it in JS:

```
<script>
  var name="$name";
</script>
```

**Edit:** As porneL said, you should not put data in the page that way without escaping it to avoid opening XSS holes.

Oh, and if you use AJAX, also pay attention on not making ajax data `text/html` or so
to avoid XSS, too.

Comment: This is insecure. You should use `<script> var = <?php echo json_encode($name); ?>`.

Comment: @porneL: Depends on where the data comes from and whether it's already encoded/escaped.

Comment: Well, then you shouldn't be relying on your luck or handling half of JS's escaping in part of application that doesn't generate JS ;P